# Python taking too much memory on server,

Tags: linux, memory, python, amazon-ec2

I have a running EC2 instance on amazon AWS. and some time server gives me the memory maximum utilization above 97%.

When i saw my server stats on [newrelic](https://rpm.newrelic.com) That showed me the below running processes and their memory usage, i can see that python is taking too much memory, while i have no application running with python, then why python is taking too much memory, 
What might be the issue, should i stop python process or this may effect the server, or any other solution, or this is normal and i keep it as it. 
[image]

Comment: You need to figure out what the python process is doing. Tools like `ps`, `lsof`, and `fuser` can help.

Comment: `ps aux | grep python` will show the full command that is running with python, see what's the path for python script